# How can I make the 1/2 inch tip of 3/4" dowels maybe 1/16 of an inch thinner so they fit in a coupling?

Tags: joinery

I want to be able to easily connect and disconnect two 3/4" dowels to each other. All the couplings I've been able to find out there, while they say they are 3/4" they do not fit tightly to 3/4" dowels. So thinking I need to make about 1/2" of the ends of dowels a uniform maybe 1/16 of an inch thinner so they fit in the couplings I have.

I hope to make a lot of these to sell so need it to be uniform and efficient. I am not a skilled wood worker and have only basic tools so a simple solution is best.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want these for and the amount of use they will see? The method I was going to suggest doesn't involve forming a round 'tenon' on the end of your dowels, instead you drill centrally and insert a thinner dowel of the correct diameter. But I was thinking that if you need these to last well wood may not be the ideal material for the tenon and this method handily allows for plastic or metal to be easily substituted.

Comment: Maybe include a simple drawing so we are all on the same page. I t may help you visualize your own solution better, as well.

Answer (score 2):

One tool you can use is called a tenon cutter. It's the equivalent of the old-school pencil sharpener, a blade adjacent to a hole into which you insert the dowel and twist.

[Amazon sells one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002JA5FY) that is designed to be used with a drill motor, but you could use it by clamping it and rotating the dowels by hand, although that would become tedious in short order.

[image: tenon cutter]

The link above references a 3/4" cutter. There are other models which are adjustable for diameter of cut. Tenon cutters would represent an investment, as the prices I've found are in the hundred dollar range, but should last through the many tenons you'll be creating.

Another method, perhaps less expensive, is to have someone bore a hole in a thick piece of steel for the correct diameter. Dowels would be hammered into the hole, with the excess diameter being sheared/scraped from the dowel.

I did a search for "DIY tenon cutter" and found an interesting [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4gO1jA2d0g), but it requires the use of a lathe to rotate the dowel at high speed. Inexpensive open end wrenches were ground to have a cutting edge on the end of one jaw, to be used as a form of lathe chisel. Not practical for basic tool owners, however.

More to the point is this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjFnMjlt6SE), which provides instruction to create one's own pencil-sharpener cutter, using a plane blade. The video describes creating a tapered tenon, but the angle can be adjusted to create a "normal" cylinder.

You suggest that someone could build a tool for you, but SE does not have the facility for such contacts.

Comment: Another method .if you only need a couple : Chuck the dole into an electric drill , run it slowly and use a rasp/ file/ sand paper to reduce the diameter of the dole .